# regex to match lines with coordinates ending in zero

Tags: regex

given the following:

```
 1803            1004    -4.2
 1807            1005    3.3
 1809            1006    -8.9
 1800            1007    -3.7
 1805            1008    9.1
 1808            1009    -4.3
 1800            1000    3.2
```

I'd like  regex to match a line with the two first coordinates that are ending in zero, so we'd only return:

```
1800            1000    3.2
```

I only want lines that have both the first two digits ending in zero, and yes the lines will have large quantities of whitespace either at the start or between the digits.

I've tried various combinations of '\s*\d+0\z*\d+0*' and '*\d+0\s*\d+0*' with no result.

I'm using this in combination with grep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend option in grep: `-E`

```
$ grep -E '^ *([0-9]*0) +([0-9]*0) +.*$' dataFile
```

Result:

[image]

In action: https://regex101.com/r/h4on2q/1

---

*Additional,*

About `-E`: `$ man grep`

```
 -E, --extended-regexp
        Interpret pattern as an extended regular expression (i.e. force grep to behave as egrep).
```

Basic vs Extended Regular Expressions: 
https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Basic-vs-Extended.html

Comment: perhaps you can add to your answer to explain what -E does? (for anyone else reading this)

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try: `^\s*\d+0\s+\d+0\s+.*$`

In action: https://regex101.com/r/t0hhDL/2

It's not clear from your question whether the data you're working with is all one big string, or these are multiple lines being returned. I assumed the latter with the answer above, but the pattern will need to be slightly different if that's not the case.

Comment: it works fine in the simulator, but doesn't like being used in grep at all :(